# issue with get_rollit_source

Tags: r, rcpp

I tried to use `get_rollit_source` from the `RcppRoll` package as follows:

```
library(RcppRoll)
get_rollit_source(roll_max,edit=TRUE,RStudio=TRUE)
```

I get an error:

```
Error in get("outFile", envir = environment(fun)) : 
  object 'outFile' not found
```

I tried

```
outFile="C:/myDir/Test.cpp"
get_rollit_source(roll_max,edit=TRUE,RStudio=FALSE,outFile=outFile)
```

I get an error:

```
Error in get_rollit_source(roll_max, edit = TRUE, RStudio = FALSE, outFile = outFile) : 
  File does not exist!
```

How can fix this issue?

I noticed that the `RcppRoll` folder in the `R` library doesn't contain any `src` directory. Should I download it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get_rollit_source` only works for 'custom' functions. For things baked into the package, you could just download + read the source code (you can download the source tarball [here](http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/RcppRoll_0.1.0.tar.gz), or go to the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/kevinushey/RcppRoll)).

Anyway, something like the following should work:

```
rolling_sqsum <- rollit(final_trans = "x * x")
get_rollit_source(rolling_sqsum)
```

(I wrote this package quite a while back when I was still learning R / Rcpp so there are definitely some rough edges...)

Comment: thanks. it's a great package, one I have been using extensively for nearly year. I never tried the `get_rollit_source` package before and just tried the example you gave. It's really cool. Awesome work!

Comment: Glad to hear you've found it useful :)